# Imagemagick, windows cmd (or similar windows console app) equivalent of "Head", piping line 1, specific characters to a .ppm file

Tags: linux, windows, cmd, command-line, imagemagick

First time posting to stackoverflow. Thanks for the help.

I need to create a .ppm file based off the most dominant color in an image's color histogram. I'm using imagemagick. I need it to work in windows.

To do so, I need a windows command equivalent of sort, head, sed: (eg: `| sort -n -k 4 | head -n 1 | sed 's/.*(//' | sed 's/,/ /g' | sed 's/ 0)//g'`)

**Main command for imagemagick (works in bash / windows git-bash.exe, needs to work in windows native):**

```
magick convert 'BMW_logo_(gray).png' -colors 5 -depth 8 -format "%c" histogram:info: | sort -n -k 4 | head -n 1 | sed 's/.*(//' | sed 's/,/ /g' | sed 's/ 0)//g'
```

Output (most dominant color):

```
107 116 122
```

These results need piped to a file and then prepended with *the* PPM file prerequisites of `P3 1 1 255` , in windows via cmd or other process that can be automated.

Eg: `P3 1 1 255 107 116 122` in a ppm file would produce a 1x1 pixel, with 255 max levels, of gray color (rgb 107 116 122).

File to pipe results to:

```
results.ppm
```

And then perform

```
&& del ppmsetup.ppm && echo P3 1 1 255 >ppmsetup.ppm && type results.ppm>>ppmsetup.ppm
```

**Which would:**

1.) Delete old ppmsetup.ppm file

2.) Write ppm prerequisites to ppmsetup.ppm

3.) Prepend ppm prerequisites (ppmsetup.ppm) to results.ppm

This .ppm file will be linked in a photoshop document as a linked smart object. I'm making an artificially intelligent designer, this is one portion.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated and likely a great contribution to this community (because it's so fun).

**Additional notes, please stop reading unless the above is not possible:**
Alternatively, doing all the same operations in git-bash.exe may work... the process starts with a user passing the file variable through windows command (QtTabBar UI shortcut passes file variable to a command line), and the file lands in a hot folder, where a hotfolder.sh script invokes runhotfolder.cmd (launches photoshop and other programs) which could run in parallel with the magick command if it was possible to pass the file variable to runhotfolder.sh, immediately before `. ../functions/"$FUNCTION".cmd` on line ~39:

```
#!/bin/bash
FUNCTION=runhotfolder
# Finding path to itself
RELPATH=$(dirname "$0")
# cd into it
cd "$RELPATH"
#make 3 new directories
mkdir in out processing
# mechanism to restart converting videos if script was aborted(computer shutdown)
FOLDERSIZE=`du -s processing | cut -f1`
# find processing/ -type f -iname *_converted* -exec rm -f {} \;
find processing/ -type f \( -name '*_converted*' -or -name '*_compressed*' \) -exec rm -f {} \;
mv processing/* in
#open a loop
while :
do
if ! [ "$(ls -A in)" ]; then
    echo 'The "in" Folder is Empty'
    # to reduce processing load lets wait some seconds till we check again. 
    sleep 5
else
    echo 'Oh something is in the "in" Folder let us watch it more closely'
    #check the size of folder in, wait 5 second check again.
    FOLDERSIZE1=`du -s in | cut -f1`
    echo $FOLDERSIZE1
    sleep 2
    FOLDERSIZE2=`du -s in | cut -f1`
    echo $FOLDERSIZE2
    sleep 2
        # if the first and secod time the foldersize didn't change and is grater than 0 start processing (we then assume that the copying into the in folder is finished)
        if [ "$FOLDERSIZE1" -eq "$FOLDERSIZE2" ] && [ "$FOLDERSIZE2" -gt 0 ]; then
            # Start Processing > Enter your code here         
            # move content from in folder to processing folder
            mv in/* processing
            # go into processing folder / make it current path
            cd ./processing
            # load a script from functions / here it actually starts the processing of the data
            # replaced source with . for bigger compatibility
            . ../functions/"$FUNCTION".cmd
            # go up one level (because in the rest of the script we assume to be at the base level of our folderstructure)
            cd ..
        else
            # this is somehow obsolete now but if there was a file with size 0 placed in the in folder this is where we would land.
            echo Size of in is still changing we assume someone is still copying their data into it.
            echo OR someone placed a file with size 0 in the in folder
        fi
fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer:

```
magick convert 'BMW_logo_(gray).png' -colors 5 -depth 8 -format "%c" histogram:info: | Sort-Object | Select -First 1 | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace ",", " "} | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "^.*?\("} | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '0\).*'}
```

CMD is built for managing basic files. To have custom outputs etc. you'll need to use powershell. Powershell equivalents for `sort`, `head` and `sed` are above.

Full answer, writing to a ppm file:

```
magick convert 'BMW_logo_(gray).png' -colors 5 -depth 8 -format "%c" histogram:info: | Sort-Object | Select -First 1 | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace ",", " "} | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "^.*?\("} | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '0\).*'} | Out-File -Path results.ppm && "P3 1 1 255 " + (Get-Content results.ppm -Raw) | Set-Content results.ppm
```